# Split up default.aspx

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-4.0

I have dynamic page which hides and shows a lot of stuff, div's, depending of what the user is clicking.
It works great however the default.aspx gets a bit messy with all that html so I wounder if it is possible to split up the html into smaller parts and still keeping the structure of the page?

Thanks
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, split up sub-sections of your code into `System.Web.UI.UserControl`s (.ascx). You have to register a tag for your control with Default.aspx, and then you can include it just like you include `<asp:` controls.

MyControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyControl" %>

<asp:Label ID="lblCoolLabel" runat="server" />
```

MyControl.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Default.aspx:

```
<!-- Registers your control -->
<%@ Register TagPrefix="controls" TagName="MyControl" Src="~/controls/MyControl.ascx" %>

<!-- Renders your control -->
<controls:MyControl ID="ucMyControl" runat="server" />
```